# Regex to match a literal pattern followed by zero or more characters followed by another literal pattern

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2015

I'm updating a file that invokes methods using this style `Foo( a )`. Notice the extra spaces around the parameter `a`. I want to replace this invocation style with a more compact one -- `Foo(a)`. How can I find all instances of the first style in my file and replace each instance with the second style? I need a regex that is something like "match the literal `(` followed by zero or more characters (including possibly whitespace) until you hit a `)`"?

I've tried `\( .* \)` but that doesn't work. Any suggestions?

I'm using Visual Studio 2015's search and replace function.

Comment: Try `\(\s+([\s\S\r]*?)\s+\)` and replace with `($1)`. If there cannot be line breaks, `\(\s+(.*?)\s+\)` will do.

Comment: If you put that as a response I'll mark it as the answer

Comment: Any chance you could translate the last one into English? I see we've got one or more occurences of the pattern "left parenthesis followed by space" (`\(\s+`) followed by zero or more occurences of any character (?) followed by 1 or more space followed by a right parenthesis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
\(\s+(.*?)\s+\)
```

and replace with `($1)`.

**Details**

- `\(` - a `(` char
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1 (`$1` in the replacement pattern refers to this value): any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `\)` - a `)` char.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yRrfKR/1) and a [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5C(%5Cs%2B(.*%3F)%5Cs%2B%5C)):

[image]

If there can be any char in between use `[\s\S\r]*?` instead of `.*?`.